# most elegant way to initialize members with default values

Tags: dart

Is there any way to make use of the initializer list to *optionally* initialize optional
parameters in a constructor? The following example resorts to **if(?x)** type
logic in the body since it is not clear how to set **_x** in the initializer list only
if it is passed in.

```dart
class Point { 
    double _x = 0.0;
    double get x => _x;
    double _y = 0.0;
    double get y => _y;

    Point(
        {
        double x,
        double y
        })
    { 
        if(?x) { _x = x; }
        if(?y) { _y = y; }
    }
}
```

An alternative is to have constructor:

```dart
Point(
      {
        double x: 0.0,
        double y: 0.0
      }) : _x = x, _y = y
{
}
```

But then you are repeating yourself (0.0 more than one place) and it looks like _x and _y get initialized twice, once for the member and then again by the initializer list. Also, a benefit of member initializer is it can be a function call, whereas default values for default parameters seem to require constants. I hope/realize the performance impact is small. Just want a nice canonical approach, likely to be used in code generation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Chris Buckett's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394313/most-elegant-way-to-initialize-members-with-default-values/15396166#15396166) is great for constants.
Apparently there is a ternary operator that does work in member
initializer. So if initialization of a field is expensive (say
requiring a function call and/or creation of objects), this approach seems to work:

- Don't bother initializing the member in the class - prefer the
  constructor(s). Otherwise, may be wasted effort.
- Skip the nice *this.member* parameter syntax. Rather use member name and
  qualify member with *this.* in the assignment.
- Make use of the *?parm* with ternary operator in member initializer. Here is an example in which creating the default values for the member is assumed expensive.

```
class Formats {
  static Map<String, dynamic> defaultFormats() {
    print("Expensive call - avoid if possible");
    return {"th": 'default th', "td": 'default td'};
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> leftTbl;
  Map<String, dynamic> rightTbl;

  Formats(
      {Map<String, dynamic>? leftTbl,
      Map<String, dynamic>? rightTbl})
      : leftTbl = leftTbl ?? defaultFormats(),
        rightTbl = rightTbl ?? defaultFormats();

  @override
  String toString() {
    return """
l => $leftTbl,
r => $rightTbl
""";
  }
}
```

Sample use:

```
print(new Formats());
print(new Formats(leftTbl: {"th":'solid #089', "td":'solid #089' }));
print(new Formats(leftTbl: {"th":'solid #189', "td":'solid #189'},
      rightTbl: {"th":'solid #189', "td":'solid #189'}));
```

Output:

```
Expensive call - avoid if possible
Expensive call - avoid if possible
l => {th: default th, td: default td},
r => {th: default th, td: default td}

Expensive call - avoid if possible
l => {th: solid #089, td: solid #089},
r => {th: default th, td: default td}

l => {th: solid #189, td: solid #189},
r => {th: solid #189, td: solid #189}
```

Comment: While this answer is great now, be sure to check the latest spec. According to this: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/misc/vlWcc43EnL4 - "? operator

Gilad: Can we get rid of it?
Lars: Yes.
Gilad: OK, done."

Comment: Thanks. I will try to understand this change and update my approach. The idea is to cleanly initialize all members, even expensive members, only once. Hopefully new/better way using member initializer is possible.

Comment: I updated this code to work with newer analysis rules and null safety. Apologies if I've broken anything here.

Answer (score 37):

You can initialize variables in a constructor using `this` prefix, eg:

```dart
class PointA { 
  double _x;
  double get x => _x;
  double _y;
  double get y => _y;

  PointA({double this._x=0.0, double this._y=0.0});
}

class PointB { 
  final double x;
  final double y;

  Point({double this.x=0.0, double this.y=0.0});
}

void main() {
  new PointA(_y:2.0); 
  new PointA(_x:3.0); 
  new PointA(_x:2.0, _y:3.0); 

  new PointB(y:2.0); 
  new PointB(x:3.0); 
  new PointB(x:2.0, y:3.0); 
}
```

Comment: That is a nice feature, unfortunately it does not correctly initialize the not passed arguments values to 0, but rather null. The first, for example initializes to (null,2.0) instead of (0.0, 2.0).

Comment: Ok, I've changed my code sample above.  This is the way I'd have done it (note the `final` keyword on the `_x` and `_y` fields - this indicates that they must be initialized as part of constructor initialization or before - it's not mandatory, but that example class "looks" like `x` and `y` are read-only)

Comment: If _x and _y are final, then there's no need for the getters, just make x and y final. That will make the constructor signature nicer too. I try to never use `this._something` in a constructor because you are exposing private internals.

Comment: @ChrisBuckett `PointA` does not compile because named parameters can not start by `_`.

Answer (score 7):

As a modification to [user1338952's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15422016/6181476), you can do:

```
class Formats { 

  static Map<String,dynamic> defaultFormats() {
    print("Expensive call - avoid if possible");
    return { 
      "th" : 'default th',
      "td" : 'default td'
    };
  }

  Map<String,dynamic> leftTbl;
  Map<String,dynamic> rightTbl;

  Formats(
      {
        Map<String,dynamic> leftTbl,
        Map<String,dynamic> rightTbl
      }) : this.leftTbl = leftTbl ?? defaultFormats(),
           this.rightTbl = rightTbl??  defaultFormats()
  { 
  }

  String toString() {
    return """
l => $leftTbl,
r => $rightTbl
""";
  }
}
```

The core difference is the use of the **if null operator**(`??`).

In `this.leftTbl = leftTbl ?? defaultFormats()`, if `leftTbl` is null, the value returned by `defaultFormats()` is simply assigned to it.