# how to initialize class with default value in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class Profile {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  
  final session = getIt<Session>();

  Profile({
    this.firstName = session.profile.firstName,
    this.lastName = session.profile.lastName
  });
}
```

This code has error says

```
The default value of an optional parameter must be constant
```

So how can I initialize class that has optional parameter and default value from other instance?

Comment: The question already asked. Just click [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394313/most-elegant-way-to-initialize-members-with-default-values)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [most elegant way to initialize members with default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394313/most-elegant-way-to-initialize-members-with-default-values)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the initialization list or the member initializer instead of initializing the attributes inside the constructor

For example:

```
class Profile {
  final String? firstName;
  final String? lastName;
  
  final session = getIt<Session>();

  Profile({
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
  })
  : firstName = firstName ?? session.profile.firstName,
    lastName = lastName ?? session.profile.lastName;
}
```